# Deploying DAO on sepolia testnet

Tags: blockchain, smartcontracts, dao

I've followed this tutorial on DAO deployment https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AhJtmUqhAqg

I've got everything working perfectly on localhost. Sepolia testnet works fine for Propose, vote. But I got an error when trying to run the Queue and execute.ts script. I saw the comment on the code ("this will fail on a testnet because you need to wait for the MIN_DELAY!") . But I'd like to know how can I change the code so that It'll run on testnet.
Thanks